# Could it be a nice coincidence of complex line integral with different path?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Given question

> Evaluate $\displaystyle\int_C(z^2+3z)\,\mathbb dz$ along
>
> 1. The circle $|z|=2$ from $(2,0)$ to $(0,2)$ in a counterclockwise direction.
> 2. The straight line from $(2,0)$ to $(0,2)$.
> 3. The straight line from $(2,0)$ to $(2,2)$ and then $(2,2)$ to $(0,2)$.

Actually all of those cases give me the answer $-\dfrac{44}{3}-\dfrac{8}{3}i$, and sorry i can't give the whole of my answer in detail, cz it'll consume a lot of time. But, i'm pretty sure i didn't make a mistake cz i did it carefully.

Then i tried to checked the function with substituting $z=x+iy$, it satisfied the C-R equation.

Could i state, in the same initial point and end point, if the path of the curve that is the function is holomorphic, then it gives the same result no matter which path that i choose?

Really? Is it just a nice coincidence or that is so?

Comment: Since the function is analytic, we know that the integral of the function on any closed loop is $0$. That ensures that the integral remains the same regardless of path. (Since a closed loop can be constructed by taking one path, and the reverse of another).

Comment: Is it still holds when it's not a closed loop. Cz my case isn't close loop?

Comment: @OP Read what I said a bit more carefully. None of the paths have to be closed loops. I'm composing a path with the inverse of another path. That must be a closed path since the first path goes from $A\to B$, and the inverse of the second path goes from $B\to A$. If that integral is $0$, that means that the integral over both paths is equal.

Comment: @DonThousand please add simply connectedness to your first comment. Otherwise we have famous counterexample $z\mapsto \frac{1}{z},z\not=0$ over $|z|=1$.

Comment: @S.D. True, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

Note that, $g:z\mapsto\frac{z^3}{3}+\frac{3z^2}{2},z\in\Bbb C$ is an antiderivative of $f:z\mapsto z^2+3z,z\in \Bbb C$ i.e. $g'=f$. Hence for any smooth parametrization $\gamma:[0,1]\to\Bbb C$ of $C$ we have, $$\int_Cf(z)dz=\int_0^1f(\gamma(t))\cdot\gamma'(t)dt$$$$=\int_0^1g'(\gamma(t))\cdot\gamma'(t)dt$$$$=\int_0^1\frac{d}{dt}\big(g(\gamma(t))\big)dt$$$$=g(\gamma(1))-g(\gamma(0))$$$$=g(0,2)-g(2,0).$$

So as long as you can find antiderivative of an analytic function defined on an open set, the integral over any path of this function only depends on the two end points of the path, irrespective of how the path actually looks like.